# How to parse redis slowlog

Tags: redis

I try to parse redis slowlog to a files with csv format (comma, column or space as delimiter), but I am not sure how to do that.

If I run `redis-cli -h <ip> -p 6379 slowlog get 2`, I get below output:

```
1) 1) (integer) 472141
   2) (integer) 1625198930
   3) (integer) 11243
   4) 1) "ZADD"
      2) "key111111"
      3) "16251.8488247"
      4) "abcd"
   5) "1.2.3.4:89"
   6) ""
2) 1) (integer) 37214
   2) (integer) 1525198930
   3) (integer) 1024
   4) 1) "ZADD"
      2) "key2"
      3) "1625.8"
   5) "1.2.3.4:89"
   6) "client-name"
```

Note the item 4) of each log entry may contain different numbers of arguments, e.g. 4) of log entry 1) has 4 arguments, while 4) of log entry 2) has 3 arguments; and the item 6) can be a string like client-name or can be empty.

If I run the command using below shell script:

```
results=$(redis-cli -h <ip> -p $port slowlog get 2)
echo $results
```

I get below output:

```
 472141 1625198930 11243 ZADD key111111 16251.8488247 abcd 1.2.3.4:89 37214 1525198930 1024 ZADD key2 1625.8 1.2.3.4:89 client-name
```

As you see, the output of the command becomes lots of words. Besides, it is hard to figure out which group of words belong to the same log entry. what I want is to get a csv file like:

```
472141 1625198930 11243 ZADD key111111 16251.8488247 abcd 1.2.3.4:89
37214 1525198930 1024 ZADD key2 1625.8 1.2.3.4:89 client-name
```

Is there anyway I can parse the redis slowlog to a cvs file  as I want? any script like python, shell is welcomed. and any existing code is welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

#!/bin/bash

CMDS=$(grep ^slowlog-max-len /etc/keydb/keydb.conf | awk '{print $2}')

IFS="
"

STATE=0
PREV_SPACES=0
SPACES=0
INARGS=false
keydb-cli --no-raw slowlog get $CMDS | while read LINE; do
  if [ $STATE -eq 0 ]; then
    STATE=1
    continue
  fi
  if $INARGS; then
    SPACES=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/^(  *)[0-9].*/\1/' | wc -c)
    if [ $SPACES -le $PREV_SPACES ]; then
      INARGS=false
      STATE=5
      CLIENT=$(echo $LINE | cut -d " -f2)
      DATE=$(date -d "@$TIMESTAMP" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      echo $DATE $TIME $CLIENT $ARGS
    elif [ "$1" = "-v" ]; then
      ARGS="$ARGS; $(echo $LINE | cut -d " -f2-)"
    fi
  else
    STATE=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ) -f1 | tr -d ' ')
    if [ $STATE -eq 2 ]; then
      TIMESTAMP=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}')
    elif [ $STATE -eq 3 ]; then
      TIME=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}')
    elif [ $STATE -eq 4 ]; then
      ARGS=$(echo $LINE | cut -d " -f2)
      PREV_SPACES=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/^(  *)[0-9].*/\1/' | wc -c)
      INARGS=true
    elif [ $STATE -eq 6 ]; then
      STATE=0
    fi
  fi
done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).